# My prefix will quench my thirst

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

My first '[Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)':

> My prefix will quench my thirst,
> my suffix is fundamentally measured,
> my infix is an ancient capital that is treasured.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are

> Hydrometer

My prefix will quench my thirst,

> Hydro = Water

my suffix is fundamentally measured,

> Meter = A fundamental measurement unit

my infix is an ancient capital that is treasured.

> Rome = Italy’s capital and used to be a part of an ancient Roman empire.

Answer (score 18):

Very similar to Kevorobin's answer but I think it might actually be

> Barometer

My prefix will quench my thirst,

> Bar

my suffix is fundamentally measured,

> Meter

my infix is an ancient capital that is treasured.

> Rome