# Riley Riddle 3: The hallmark of a good riddle

Tags: riddle

This cookie's perspective, perhaps influenced by tones
Bottom's after Siwa, the Nome(sp?) of round stones
If money's a coin, the cream's the flip side
Top's where you look when you know you've replied

Hint 1:

> The suffix is easier if you know Assassin's Creed: Origins. The infix is a common idiom. The prefix is a staple feature of any messaging service.

Hint 2:

> The full word is closely related to greeting cards and also related to certain cookie jars (hence the cookie theme)

Comment: I didn't downvote this post, but I think this riddle can not be categorized as "Riley Riddle". The [original Riley's riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) has a specific format (prefix, suffix, infix)

Comment: This riddle follows that format. It just references each part in a unique way (the bottom is the suffix, the top is the prefix, and the cream is the infix, like a cookie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this

> SENTIMENT?

Top's where you look when you know you've replied

> You'd look in the SENT folder

If money's a coin, the cream's the flip side

> TIME is money.

Bottom's after Siwa, the Nome(sp?) of round stones

> The IMENT Nome comes after Siwa in Assassin's Creed: Origins.

Comment: Indeed! A sentiment is the perspective you might have around a situation or event, influenced by the tones of that event or the message shared.  Greeting cards are purchased because of the sentiment they share, and sentiment cookie jars are common knick-knack :) The title is a reference to Hallmark Sentiments, a series of "discount" cards produced by the popular greeting card publisher.