# Full Of Abbreviations!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> With only the beginning, I am an abbreviation of the whole word (Commonly found in games)
>
> In the middle, I can be considered as an abbreviation of a school subject
>
> While with the ending, I may be used as a very rude abbreviation
>
> My Whole is a noun

Additional Hint :

> The word consists of just 8 letters

Comment: I have just three questions: **1.** (ROT13) Qbrf gur ortvaavat ersre gb n ZNC? **2.** (ROT13)  Ol n "fhowrpg", qb lbh zrna n fpubby fhowrpg yvxr Zngu, Fpvrapr, Uvfgbel, rgp? **3.** (ROT13) Ubj qb lbh znxr fhpu vagrerfgvat Evyrl Evqqyrf? :D

Comment: Answer : 1. Yes it does 2. Yes, that is what I meant 3. Is it really? I thought mine was quite bad? :) @user477343

Comment: Well, I find all Riley Riddles interesting. It shows off interesting properties about whatever word the answer is. In fact, I tend to be curious most of the time, so I can find anything interesting. You have made heaps of Riley Riddles, and thus far, I have not grown bored yet, hahah!

Comment: Lol. I may not be as active once I start school in October but I'll still try to make some :) @user477343. Btw, have found anything yet?

Comment: Yeah, lucky I'm doing fine in school, otherwise I'd might have to temporarily stop making riddles. I have stopped here and there just to study for tests and things, but I'm good now. **Edit:** Also, doing a little bit of research, it seems like (ROT13) gurer ner bayl guerr rvtug-yrggre jbeqf fgnegvat jvgu ZNC. V nz tbvat sbe ZNCZNXRE, ohg V pna'g svaq gur fpubby fhowrpg uvqqra va vg. V gubhtug NCZN zvtug unir fgbbq sbe Nccyvrq Zngurzngvpf, ohg V qba'g guvax gung vf va fpubby (cevznel / frpbaqnel).

Comment: Vg qbrfa'g fgneg jvgu gur jbeq ZNC. Lbh znl unir gb tb onpx gb gur qenjvat obneq :) @user477343

Comment: @user477343 Why call "Riley Riddle" what is merely a [charade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charades)?

Comment: @xhienne Hmm... good point. But I think charades is more physical, like how a person must act the word out, whereas this is just a simple riddle. Perhaps a charade riddle? I think "Riley Riddle" has a bit of a touch to it, though :)

Comment: @user477343 I think you are talking about what is called "Acted charades" in the WP article. I'm talking about "[Literary charades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charades#Literary_charades)", a kind of riddle which has existed for more than two centuries. Riley riddles seem quite different to me (if memory serves, the whole is not given and the infix overlaps the prefix and the suffix).

Comment: @xhienne oh, so sorry for not looking down at more of the WP article. Yes, it does seem it is quite a literary charade. And yes, Riley Riddles are different as you said, especially when comparing their average format, but reading through the entire literary charades article, they are indeed very similar. I suppose that for this specific question, I think it is a bit of both, but intended to be more of a Riley Riddle... though apparently [this creepy video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPgJhjBY_34) disagrees with WP's definition of a literary charade...

Comment: @user477343 Well, this is just a video. WP definition is exact. And if you look at [an original Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) you'll notice that it is quite different from a charade, literary or not, because of the overlapping infix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> **STRENGTH**?

With only the beginning, I am an abbreviation of the whole word (Commonly found in games)

> Strength is often shortened to **STR** in RPGs

In the middle, I can be considered as an abbreviation of a school subject

> **ENG** is short for English

While with the ending, I may be used as a very rude abbreviation

> **GTH**, as in "Go to hell!" (Thanks @mrdeadsven!)

My Whole is a noun

> 'Strength' is a noun

Comment: Correct Answer! Only the ending part is wrong (Figure it out and I will give the checkmark) :)

Comment: @KevinL Might it be rot13(Tb Gb Uryy, fvapr vg frrzf yvxr jr ner hfvat nooerivngvbaf bs 3 nyy gur gvzr?)

Comment: @mrdeadsven ROT13 (Lbh ner gbgnyyl pbeerpg!)

Comment: Thanks @mrdeadsven!  Not sure how I came up with my guess...yours actually uses all the letters.  =)

Comment: Congrats! All correct. Clearly you are a master puzzle solver :) @hagfy

Answer (score 5):

First thing that came to my mind was

> DUNGEONS

With only the beginning, I am an abbreviation of the whole word

> If I go back to my Dungeons & Dragons (D&D) times D was abbreviation of Dungeons

Commonly found in some games

> Lots of games have dungeons

In the middle, I can be considered as an abbreviation of a school subject

> GEO from geography

While with the ending, I may be used as a very rude abbreviation

> not sure was thinking of NS for No Shit?

Comment: +1 but incorrect. All the parts were wrong

Comment: @KevinL unfortunate but I still had my fun thinking over this nice riddle :p, hopefully someone else has a better clue on it.

Comment: Yours was still a nice answer though :)