# Riley riddles galore!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle, acrostic

My new '[Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)' is different:

> Where my prefix is getting something from you,
>
> Here my suffix makes food last longer,
>
> You think my infix is on edge,
>
> Underthinking it is not what I do.

+ Think it through

Comment: Good is different, and different is good. $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to guess:

> Consideration

Where my prefix is getting something from you,

> Con - A person tries to con you out of money or something valuable

Here my suffix makes food last longer,

> Ration - Rationing food makes it last longer.

You think my infix is on edge,

> Side - A triangle has 3 sides, three edges. Side of the road, edge of the road, they're pretty synonymous in some cases.

Underthinking it is not what I do.

> If you give something consideration, it means you're thinking it over thoroughly.

+ Think it through

> Give this riddle some consideration.

Answer (score 2):

How I haven't seen this one yet I'm not sure; but to begin breaking this down, the acrostic is:

> WHYU $\leftarrow$ In which I believe the **WHY** is the only relevant portion.

*Where my prefix is getting something from you,*

> I think this could be a literal statement in which we get a letter or letters from **you**. So the answer to this could be *y, o, u, yo, yu, oy, ou, uy, uo*; however, the only ones that make sense as a prefix would be *y, o, u, yo, oy*. Due to the acrostic containing a **U** I believe the letter is most likely **U** as it is what I would do; the letter **U** is difficult to use unless you're trying to ensure its usage as a hint, just like the letters *Q, V, X, Z*.

*Here my suffix makes food last longer,*

> 

*You think my infix is on edge,*

> I think the infix could possibly be **e** following the same concept as the prefix. Words that are synonymous to *on edge* are *tense, excited, wired, nervous, eager, impatient, edgy, etc...* and I believe the most likely words would be **tense, eager, antsy, or edgy**.

*Under thinking it is not what I do.*

> 

Comment: Why u think it through