# The Riley Riddle Mine

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a doctor.
>
> My suffix isn't feeling well.
>
> My infix is myself.
>
> From earth to enamel, what am I?

---

*As usual, please supplement final answers with explanations for each line. This '[Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)' is my first. Feedback welcome.*

Comment: Hopefully the prefix can help out the suffix :)

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain the downvote? Feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you are a

> DRILL.

```
My prefix is a doctor.
```

> DR

```
My suffix isn't feeling well.
```

> ILL

```
My infix is myself.
```

> I

```
From earth to enamel, what am I?
```

> Drills are used (among many other things) for drilling into the earth (e.g., for oil) and for drilling through tooth enamel.

Comment: Dang it!  I over-complicated my answer...

Comment: And dang! Solved 7 views in. Oh, well.

Comment: Should have made it harder, then :-).

Comment: Sure should have.

Comment: There's no harm in having some easy puzzles. Unless you are keen for them not to be solved too quickly, of course.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying to consistently find a balance that I like between a five-second riddle and a five-day riddle. Some have been too long, a few just right, and many too short.

Answer (score 4):

Are you a:

> Dremel?

My prefix is a doctor.

> Dr. Dre

My suffix isn't feeling well.

> Your are ill which sounds like "el"

My infix is myself.

> Me

From earth to enamel, what am I?

> A dremel is a power tool company that makes things like rotary saws, cleaners.  I think the saw is used by dentist for certain procedures

Comment: So close! Gareth did get the correct answer.