# A Warm Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My infix has been removed.
>
> My suffix is this.
>
> If you can read this, you're on my prefix.
>
> If you read this in the morning, you might guess me sooner - what am I?

*The usual. Please have an explanation for each line and the title.*

***Hint #1:***

> For the third line, I've heard/guessed that some of you are thinking of things like the SE network or the "web" or the "net". You're going down the right path, but the answer to this part of the riddle is a bit more broad than "internet." Not much more broad, but a little bit.

Comment: Does *this* refer to the subject of the riddle?

Comment: @noedne maybe....... Actually no.

Comment: I thought the same as @noedne :P

Comment: @MrPie haha sorry, but still no.

Comment: I believe I got the prefix, but the rest I'm completely at a loss, especially the suffix clue...

Comment: @PiIsNot3 I promise that the suffix will make the most sense when you're done.

Comment: @PiIsNot3 how does it look now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With thanks to hexomino for getting me thinking the right way:

You are a

> **Griddle**

Prefix=

> '**grid**' as in 'on the grid,' meaning using electricity

Infix=

> '**rid**' which can mean to remove

Suffix=

> '**riddle**' is definitely what the question is!

As for the last line and title:

> griddles warm food up, especially breakfast food

Comment: Very well done! Checkmark coming in now.

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer might be

> Breakfast

My infix has been removed.

> I think this is a "space" which has been removed. Breakfast originates from the phrase *break fast*.

My suffix is this.

> This clue is short and *fast*.

If you can read this, you're on my prefix.

> If you're reading this riddle, you might be on a *break*.

If you read this in the morning, you might guess me sooner - what am I?

> Breakfast is a morning meal.

Comment: Nope! Not bad, though; have an upvote. FYI: I'm not _thrilled_ with my infix clue, and my prefix clue is always true, not just a "likely" thing.

Answer (score 3):

Could you be a very particular kind of recurring warmth called a

> [**sextan**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sextan)?

That would make your prefix

> [**SE**](https://stackexchange.com/) - Stack Exchange - which we're all on,

your infix

> **x**, which used to be an official movie rating in the US, but [has been removed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system#X_replaced_by_NC-17),

and your suffix

> **tan**, which is Spanish for "this" as in "She is this tall" - "Ella es tan alta".

Comment: Very nice answer! However, no language knowledge is needed (outside of English).

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be

> **soup**

My infix has been removed

> **ou** from out

My suffix is this.

> **p** for point

If you can read this, you're on my prefix.

> **s** for see

If you read this in the morning, you might guess me sooner - what am I?

> within The News we can find **stew**

A Warm Riley Riddle

> Hot soup

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, and thanks for the answer! I'm not sure that I understand how your explanation for the last line works; also, Riley Riddle "fixes" are usually whole words (and they are this time).

Comment: I've changed the answer to the last line. Not sure what you meant by 'fixes' though. Is there a rule I've missed?

Comment: "fixes" - infix, prefix, suffix

Comment: Thanks. It was looking so promising, too...

Answer (score 1):

Cannot get to fit all the clues, but I find this to be an interesting answer (edited to fit in the second clue):

> Coffee

My infix has been removed.

> off

My suffix is this.

> ee, may be pronounced as "double e", which in turn sounds like doublet--another name for word ladder puzzle, which this puzzle is in a loose sense.

If you can read this, you're on my prefix.

> If you can see (C) this

If you read this in the morning, you might guess me sooner - what am I?

> The morning coffee :)

The title

> The coffee sure may be warm but not sure about riley.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and welcome to Puzzling.SE! As a note, the "riley" part references the format of the riddle, which is drawn from a [popular riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) by a user named Riley. Searching for "Riley Riddle" on this site will produce a lot of results.