# My suffix is short for the place where you are…

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, english, poetry

> My suffix is short for the place where you are,
>
> My infix for who,
>
> My prefix for where you can learn about what's
>
> Mistaken for me in a crowd at least two.
>
> To echo a [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/48337) that's greatly renowned...
>
> I come in rounds.

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An eccentric possibility is an

> ellipse

My suffix is short for the place where you are,

> PSE - short for Puzzling Stack Exchange

My infix for who,

> I - for myself

My prefix for where you can learn about what's mistaken for me in a crowd at least two.

> ELL - short for English Language Learners, which has a linguistics [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) [tag](/questions/tagged/tag), which is also the plural (at least two) of ellipse.

To echo a riddle that's greatly renowned ... I come in rounds.

> An ellipse is a closed curve that goes around, and there are ellipses in the title and body of this question ...

This puzzle also features the answer three times:

> Ellipsis, the omission of words that are understood, or the punctuation mark **...**, is used in:
>  My infix for who - omits *you are*
>  Mistaken for me in a crowd at least two - omits *of me*
>  To echo a riddle that's greatly renowned ... - has the ellipsis punctuation mark (may also omit *here* as it's famous on PSE).

Comment: Excellent! But there is an additional explanation for the third clue (My prefix...two.) which also appears in the puzzle.

Comment: @noedne, if along the same lines maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_of_Language_and_Linguistics)?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, the place is the same, but there is another thing you can learn about there that looks the same and appears (or doesn't?) in the puzzle.

Comment: @noedne, now I think it's more like this [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))!

Comment: Yes, in fact it is even a tag on the other site.

Comment: Thank you for improving your answer, but can I ask one more thing? Can you find the (three) uses of this linguistic feature in the text of the puzzle?

Comment: Hope I haven't omitted one, or got something wrong ...

Comment: Hmm, they were actually supposed to be more definite than a couple of those, but I guess they still weren't so clear after all. Like many examples of [thing], they're all based on the parallelism between the clauses in the first three lines, namely "is short" and "you are" in the second line and "is short" in the third. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for adding this.