# Who am I ? [ Not in Stack Exchange ;) ]

Tags: riddle, word

$\color{blue}{\text{My first name}}$

> $\small\bullet$ Prefix is a country, but I don't belong to there
>   $\small\bullet$ Infix is the name of a saint
>   $\small\bullet$ Suffix is a preposition

$\color{blue}{\text{My last name}}$

> $\small\bullet$ It actually symbolizes my character
>   $\small\bullet$ Be careful! Don't get struck by it...

Who am I ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Usain Bolt

Prefix is a country, but I don't belong to there

> Us-, as in U.S., but Usain is from Jamaica.

Infix is the name of a saint

> Eh, this one's sketchy. Sain as in saint? I dunno. The "s" was already used for the prefix.

Suffix is a preposition

> in?

Last name: It actually symbolizes my character. Be careful! Don't get struck by it...

> Bolt, as in lightning bolt? It's definitely symbolic of his speed as a runner.

Comment: The saint is probably [sai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_Baba_of_Shirdi)

Comment: Ah, yeah, maybe. Still poses the problem of a letter being used for more than one role. But maybe I misunderstood the meaning of infix in this context?

Comment: @AleksandrH In Riley riddles, the infix usually overlaps with the prefix and suffix. [See: the original](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)

Comment: @scatter Interesting! Good to know.

Comment: As sid stated, it is **Sai**