# What word am I? (Riley riddle)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My ending is beginning.
My beginning is the end of middle.
My middle holds it all together.
Now read again this riddle!

Comment: The original Riley riddle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final Answer

> RESTART

My ending is beginning.

> START

My beginning is the end of middle.

> co-RE

My middle holds it all together.

> STAR - holds the planets in orbit with its gravity

Now read again this riddle!

> RESTART

Previous

> RESUME 
>  My ending is beginning. 
>  word-play - "My Ending" the beginning letters of those words are ME 
>  My beginning is the end of middle. 
>  co-RE 
>  My middle holds it all together. 
>  SUM holds all those added together 
>  Now read again this riddle!
>  After interrupting the riddle while solving each line, one would be told to RESUME reading this riddle without interruption

Comment: Not quite - as you say, some of it is a bit of a stretch. ;) But this answer has some elements that are on the right track.

Comment: I see that you changed your answer since I commented - you're on the right track.

Comment: @Gordon, I changed it again. This is it though. I've had my chances.

Comment: Your final answer is correct! Nice work. Although your interpretation of one of the clues is not the one I had intended, you still arrived at the right conclusion, and I figured that if Bilbo Baggins can get credit for "time" without actually solving the riddle, it's the destination that counts, not the precise journey. ;)

Comment: @Gordon, where you looking for rot13(gne?)

Comment: gungfjungvunqvazvaq

Answer (score 6):

You might be

> LEGO

My ending is beginning.

> le-GO

My beginning is the end of middle.

> midd-LE

My middle holds it all together.

> The middle of a lego is where it holds on to the next piece

Now read again this riddle!

> building a lego structure

Comment: Clever - as a fan of the blocks, I enjoyed your solution. :) Your interpretation of "my middle" misses the spirit of the Riley Riddle style (e.g. middle=infix), focusing more on the meaning of the word than on the word itself.

Comment: @Gordon, I guess I'll have to look up what that is. Thx.

Comment: I added a link to the original in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling this is a tricksy one. A bit of a rogue thought this, but is the word:

> **MY**?

*My ending is beginning.*

> The ending 'MY' is also the beginning, since the word is just 2 letters long...

*My beginning is the end of middle.*

> Being 2 letters long in its totality, the beginning 'MY' is not just the *end* of the middle - it's also the start of the middle and the whole of the middle!

*My middle holds it all together.*

> The central ('middle') component 'MY' is the *entirety* of the word, i.e. It '**holds it *all***'.

*Now read again this riddle!*

> Reading it through again with this answer in mind, you can see how this tricksy bit of [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) makes sense...!

Comment: Not quite - perhaps too "rogue" an attempt. ;) Read the riddle linked in my comment to get an idea of the spirit of the genre.

Comment: @GordonBean Oh, I'm very familiar with the genre - I just wondered whether you were riffing off it and giving it an 'outside the box' twist... Clearly not, though! :) (And to be honest, I'm glad this is incorrect - it wouldn't have been a satisfying solution...!)

Comment: Haha! Fair enough.