# A Riley riddle to end the year!

Tags: riddle, seasonal, affix-riddle

A [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) from my neighbour:

> Ma prefex es a salfush beest,
>   Ma suffex es oor ‘Noo’.
>   Ma enfex es joos tha’, yous sees,
>   Ma all, oor fustive doo.

Um, I'm not sure if you caught all that, so allow me to provide an alternative rendering:

> Their prefix is a greedy swine,
>   Their suffix their negation.
>   Their infix I’d consider ‘mine’,
>   Their whole their celebration!

**What is the answer to my neighbour's riddle, and where do we both live?**

(Please explain both riddles and the title!)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer:

> You live in Scotland, so you're talking about Scottish New Year, or [Hogmanay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogmanay)

Explanations:

> The first riddle is written with a Scottish accent, and reads like this (very inaccurate):
>  **My prefix is a selfish beast,
>
>  My suffix is our 'No'.
>
>  My infix is just that, you see,
>
>  My all, our festive do.**

The solution to the riddle (2nd one, but suits for 1st)

Their prefix is a greedy swine,

> **HOG**

Their suffix their negation.

> **NAY** (Scottish for "No")

Their infix I’d consider ‘mine’,

> **MA** (Scottish for "My", as can be seen in 1st riddle)

Their whole their celebration!

> **HOGMANAY** (Scottish New Year's eve which explains the title)

Comment: Correct! And almost a spot-on interpretation of the dialect. If you can correct 'too' to 'do' in the last line of your translation, I'll give you the checkmark :) Also, I was actually thinking of the 'neighbours' being rot13(Ratynaq naq Fpbgynaq), which makes sense of why I used 'their' insted of 'our' throughout the second riddle, but your way works well too of course (no need to adjust it). +1 and Happy New Year!

Comment: **festive do** surely.

Comment: Great. It's yours! :)