# Some text I'll riddle for you

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Having a go at a [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude).

> My prefix is exploitative
>
> My suffix is judgemental
>
> My infix is problematic
>
> All I do is hang around

**What am I?**

Hint:

> See if you can figure out the title!

Comment: Is the suffix rot13(ntr)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indebted by Stiv's answer, are you

> tapestry

My prefix is exploitative

> **tap** - a device used to secretly intercept communication, or exploit resources - credit OP!

My suffix is judgemental

> **try** - to put to test or on trial

My infix is problematic

> **pest** -  a nuisance

All I do is hang around

> a decorative cloth hung on walls

See if you can figure out the title!

> Tapestry is textile which sounds like 'text I'll' - found by Stiv.

Comment: D'oh, of course! Great spot :) +1

Comment: @Stiv -  I put a prefix on you for a suffix, hope it doesn't make me a infix, or it'll be your answers for me.

Comment: WOAH! This just went totally meta!

Comment: You got it, nice work! rot13(Gnc pna nyfb zrna gb rkcybvg erfbheprf) so feel free to edit that into your answer. I would appreciate it. :)

Comment: Thanks @Tonkleton for this definitive explanation, and for the nice Riley.

Answer (score 5):

I wonder whether the answer is:

> **CURTAIN**

*My prefix is exploitative*

> A **CUR** is a scoundrel or rascal, exploiting others for their own gain.

*My suffix is judgemental*

> If something is **IN**, it is considered fashionable, usually at the expense of other things. Similarly, those in the '**IN**-crowd' decide who is cool and who is not - it's all about judging others.

*My infix is problematic*

> An **RTA** is a *road traffic accident* - a problem for anybody involved in one.

*All I do is hang around*

> A curtain *hangs around* from a curtain rail, to cover a window or alcove.

As for the title:

> This could be read as '*Some **textile** riddle for you*' - a hint that the object we are looking for (a curtain) is made of fabric.

Comment: This is a great answer, but not quite the one I was looking for. Bonus points for figuring out the title though!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I know this isn't correct, but I couldn't resist. I think you are a:

> DELINQUENT

My prefix is exploitative

> DEL in Spanish means "of the", or "from the". When someone takes something "of the"/"from the" other, that's exploitative behavior.

My suffix is judgmental

> An ENT would be judgmental of humans due to greater age and steadier judgment.

My infix is problematic

> The Spanish INQUisition would be problematic for others of non-Catholic beliefs.

All I do is hang around

> Instead of going to school!!!

Title: Some text I'll riddle for you

> If a DELINQUENT goes to class, they might be texting some riddles to their friends instead of paying attention... or riddling their texts for their next text...

The primary reason I couldn't resist was...

> The Inquisition can't be stopped :o

Answer (score -1):

I wonder whether the answer is:

> **PROQUESTIONHATER**

My prefix is exploitative

> **PRO** : a pro is kind of exploitative at work

My suffix is judgemental

> **HATER** : obviously

My infix is problematic

> **QUESTION** : speaks for itself

All I do is hang around

> Thats what the procrastinator only does basically.

As for the title:

> "I'll" do it later