# My prefix is a memory; my infix, you may hate

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My prefix is a memory
>   My infix, you may hate
>   My suffix is worth an effort
>   I am used to decorate

Who am I?

Comment: Great minds think alike :) https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92445/some-text-ill-riddle-for-you

Comment: @Tonkleton Haha nice! Too bad spoiler content cannot be searched. Interesting how the clues are entirely different :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you a

> TAPESTRY?

My prefix is a memory

> Memories are kept, perhaps, on a video or cassette TAPE

My infix, you may hate

> You may hate a PEST

My suffix is worth an effort

> That is, it’s worth a TRY

I am used to decorate

> A TAPESTRY is used to decorate halls and castles.

Comment: A precise answer!