# This is a Rilerdl

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My prefix's full of expertise
My infix's in the diocese
My suffix's citation missing link
My whole's making a sink sync

What am I?

<sub>A [Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)</sub>

Comment: Warning for solvers - I took significant artistic license with the interpretation of some of the clues to make the rhyming work better; the [tag:wordplay] is most likely to lead you to the solution :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a guess, but there's one clue that I can't figure out exactly.

Are you...

> Pronunciation

My prefix's full of expertise

> A pro(fessional) is someone who is an expert at something.

My infix's in the diocese

> A nun might live in a diocese.

My suffix's citation missing link

> This one I'm not sure of, but the suffix "ciation" is citation missing the "t". If we associate the missing "t" with "missing link" then this works.

My whole's making a sink sync

> Sink can be made into sync by pronouncing it (i.e. saying it aloud).

This is a Rilerdl

> Another hint, "This is a Riley riddle" if you just pronounce it.

Comment: Everything's correct - well done!

Comment: I thought the artistic license you took on the clues were nicely creative. It's always better when it rhymes :) Thanks for the great puzzle!

Comment: [This](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MNIZDWW) is a way to *link*, say, the two drains of a double sink to a single drainpipe.