# Ten-second riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

My start's somewhere down below
My middle's what sleep does bestow
My end's a value close enough
My whole's probably not that tough

What am I?

<sub>A [Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are an:

> **UNDERESTIMATE**

*My start's somewhere down below*

> **UNDER** is a synonym for 'down below'.

*My middle's what sleep does bestow*

> Sleep brings you **REST**.

*My end's a value close enough*

> An **ESTIMATE** is an educated guess or an approximation ('close enough').

*My whole's probably not that tough*

> An **UNDERESTIMATE** (i.e. something that has been *underestimated*) has been deemed 'probably not that tough' - but beware! Things aren't always what they seem, and may turn out tougher than you first think...

**Post Script:**

> It seems from the title that the OP may have *underestimated* just how quickly this riddle would be solved!

Comment: More than 10 seconds! Shame... ;) ;)

Comment: The third clue asks for a noun, and you gave an adjective. Perhaps lop off the last letter?

Comment: @Acccumulation The answer is close enough ;)

Comment: @Accumulation Agree, and changed! :)

Comment: @Avi Feel free to roll back my answer to the one ending in -D if you prefer it...