# This One Word Will Capture Your Attention

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix might be a bash for computer users.
>   My first infix is a lap, perhaps.
>   My second infix is an antioxidant, kind of.
>   My suffix is a small island.
>   When I'm assembled, I'm strangely attractive.

**What is the word?**

Comment: [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349) #53326118

Comment: [Context for above](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53326118#53326118) (warning: spoilers)

Comment: It's not my fault, *I was provoked*

Comment: [The answer, in song.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVn7sLDhZBw) (Warning: spoilers.)

Comment: You actually did it lol @Avi take note

Comment: @Brandon_J I'm aware :)

Comment: Amazing. Absolutely amazing.

Comment: Also, @Rubio, you've been keeping count?

Comment: @North ... see HTM's comment, and in particular, pay attention to its URL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My prefix might be a bash for computer users.

> A **CLI** is a command-line interface such as the [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)).

My first infix is a lap, perhaps.

> To lap is to **LICK** up water quickly.

My second infix is an antioxidant, kind of.

> Apparently, **BAI** is a drinks company known for its "[antioxidant infusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bai_Brands)". (Avi told me so in the Sphinx's Lair. Thanks!)

My suffix is a small island.

> An **AIT** is a small island in a river.

When I'm assembled, I'm strangely attractive.

> You are **CLICKBAIT**.

Comment: No chemistry symbols or element/ion names involved in this riddle. :)

Comment: I don't care. I only came for the cat photos ... `:)`

Comment: Indeed. Well played :)

Answer (score 7):

I think you are a

> clinch

My prefix might be a bash for computer users.

> CLI - a Unix command-line interpreter, which may be bash.

My first infix is a lap, perhaps.

> li -  is a Chinese unit of distance, about a third of an English mile.

My second infix is an antioxidant

> I - iodine (or its ion) is an antioxidant.

My suffix is a small island.

> inch - a small island in Ireland or Scotland.

When I'm assembled, I'm strangely attractive.

> clinch - embrace or a fastening.

Comment: No chemistry symbols or element/ion names involved in this riddle. :)