# Shape into a spindle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> Start with a way 
>   to merge what you choose 
>   Hope not too short 
>   for you to lose
>
> Then a short delay 
>   Wait there if you may 
>   Take one more step 
>   For an aeon you'll stay

Who am I?

Hint #1:

> The first 4 lines gives two clues for the same part of the answer.

Hint #2

> The title refers to its etymology

Hint #3

> The answer is 8 letters long.

Hint #4

> I can be found in the sky if not on the ground.

Hint #5

> As a [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/18418), the first four lines refer to the prefix, the fifth line is the infix and the last line hints the suffix. Only the infix and suffix overlap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> fuselage

Start with a way \ to merge what you choose

Hope not too short \ for you to lose

> fuse - can mean merge; alternatively a short fuse could cause problems =)

Then a short delay

> lag - a lag is a short delay

Wait there if you may \ Take one more step \ For an aeon you'll stay

> age - an age is an aeon, and is one step over from lag in the solution

Regarding the title:

> the latin for spindle is 'fusus.' It came to us via French 'fuseler,’ meaning *’[shape into a spindle](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fuselage)’*. I suppose the fuselage of a plane is somewhat spindle shaped. In biology and botany, spindle shaped objects are called fusiform, which sent me in the right direction. =)

Comment: Great job, this looks to be the right answer!

Comment: Well done! I have just added an extra link for a direct relationship to the title.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't figured it all out but I think the answer is

> Coleoptera

Start with a way

> **Col** = the lowest point of a ridge between two peaks, typically providing a pass (a way) from one side of a mountain range to another.

to merge what you choose

> **Opt** = make a choice.
>  We merge 'col' with 'opt' using the letter 'e'

Hope not too short

> The merge point is a single letter.

for you to lose

> Not sure about the loss part here, maybe referring to the negative charge of the electron, referred to by the letter 'e'

Then a short delay
Wait there if you may

> Not sure about these lines but it may refer to the fact that it is quite common to abbreviate Coleoptera to Coleopt.

Take one more step

> Next letters.

For an aeon you'll stay

> **Era** - a long and distinct period of history.

Title

> Many beetles may be described as distinctly spindle-shaped.

Comment: Nice thinking! But not the answer I’m afraid :) The short delay doesn’t match too well.

Answer (score 2):

You might be

> stitching fabric with thread using a sewing machine

Start with a way 
to merge what you choose

> Depending on the type of stitch, 2 threads could be used
>  Or you are choosing fabrics to combine

Hope not too short 
for you to lose

> If your thread runs short, the stitch will be lost

Then a short delay 
Wait there if you may

> As the thread progresses through the stitch, it waits for the next stitch to pass through it

Take one more step 
For an aeon you'll stay

> The stitched together fabric will stay together for a long time

Thoughts

> I have a couple of answers that fit but there may also be wordplay involved (aeon, the use of time) that could possibly point to Einstein and spacetime. Example being, space and time woven together to form the fabric of space and time. (So, the answer could also be possibly God stitching a tear in the fabric of time and space.)
>  However, if this is a Riley Riddle, disregard everything I said. :)

Comment: Pretty good answer :), but the word tag means that the answer is a single word. Also, the last two lines still doesn’t quite fit as the rot13(fgvpuvat) won’t last long unless it passes through multiple steps.