# Single Minded Riley

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My first crack at a '[Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude)':

> My Prefix is full of class
> My Infix is deceased
> My Suffix is unorthodox
> My Whole is one-sided

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are:

> **UNILATERAL**

*My Prefix is full of class*

> As an educational establishment, **UNI** (University) is full of *class* (i.e. lectures, etc.).

*My Infix is deceased*

> **LATE** is a synonym for 'deceased' (e.g. 'the late Mr so-and-so'...).

*My Suffix is unorthodox*

> **LATERAL** thinking (e.g. to crack a riddle) is not the way one would usually think, hence unorthodox...

*My Whole is one-sided*

> Altogether, this makes **UNILATERAL**, which means quite literally, 'one-sided'.

Comment: Looks about right :)

Comment: And indeed it is. Nice one as always Stiv!