# A Demanding Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Another [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) for you, but with a slight twist!

> Take two from my prefix, a large plot of land it is
> Take five from my infix, it becomes hers or his
> Take two from my suffix, there's no better can you do
> Take all together, it's something you must see to
>
> Alas, the three smaller parts are missing two things
> Prepend the first and third so meaning you might bring

Hint:

> These 'fixes alone, they just make no sense
>  But still, the answer is not purely pretense
>  No matter how many we take, whether it be two or five
>  The last line tells us all need two more for meaning to arrive

Comment: I keep reading that title as "A demanding Ridley Riddle" lol

Comment: I've realized a frankly ridiculous mistake in my original puzzle that made it not a good puzzle at all. I've modified it so as to preserve the spirit of the puzzle -- the answer and method of solution are almost precisely the same. However, if folks think this should be closed I will certainly do so. I apologize if I've wasted your time. :(

Comment: The puzzle says two, five, and two; the hint differs.  Which is correct?

Comment: Changed the hint to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The final couplet is telling us to...

> ... prepend AC to the specified 'fixes.

Accordingly,

> "a large plot of land" is an **ACRE**
>  "it becomes hers or his" when they **ACQUIRE** it
>  "there's no better can you do" once you've **ACED** something

The answer, then...

> ... is **REQUIRED**, so you "must see to" it.

Comment: How about rot13(NPDHVER naq NPRQ sbe svany nafjre ERDHVERQ, juvpu eryngrf gb bgure yvarf naq gvgyr?)

Comment: I think rot13(guvf qbhoyrf gur R; ER/DHVER/RQ), but yeah, it makes sense...

Comment: Though I'd want something like rot13(ERDHVERZRAG, gb zngpu gur cneg bs fcrrpu vzcyvrq ol yvar 4).

Comment: Never mind—rot13(ERDHVERQ jbhyq jbex... "fbzrguvat lbh zhfg frr gb" vf erdhverq).

Comment: These kinds of riddles often have overlap between 'fixes - might be worth a shot? :)

Comment: Oh, not sure why I didn't consider that.  Good call. :)

Comment: @mbingo You got it, nice job!