# There's Still Good In You

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

My first [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude). Enjoy.

> My Prefix - A+ Place where work to get done, Suffix might send. 
>   My Infix - Procedure that can be performed on a tom or some hen. 
>   My Suffix - Place to go with brevity, if wrong way limbs do bend. 
>   My Whole - Feature not representing a faction of darkness, my friend. 
>   When finished, type the word that is built with these pieces I lend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's

> **ALABASTER**

My Prefix - A+ Place where work to get done, Suffix might send.

> The literal '**A**', and work can get done in a **LAB**oratory
> Specifically, you might get X-rays done for your broken limbs

My Infix - Procedure that can be performed on a tom or some hen.

> You might **BASTE** a (Tom) turkey or (hen) chicken

My Suffix - Place to go with brevity, if wrong way limbs do bend.

> If you break a limb, head to the Emergency Room, or **ER**

My Whole - Feature not representing a faction of darkness, my friend.

> **ALABASTER** is white, the opposite of black/darkness

When finished, type the word that is built with these pieces I lend.

> **ALABASTER**

Title:

> Luke Skywalker says "There is still good in him" regarding Darth Vader, who wears a large, imposing suit of black armor.  But [what if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Infinities) his good/light side had won...

Comment: Very likely that this is it :)

Comment: You are correct. Nice job. I just thought rot13(Gvgyr jnf Fgne Jnef ersrerapr, zr cvpghevat Inqre ba gur yvtug fvqr ybbxvat yvxr n tvnag juvgr fgnghr.)

Comment: @MacGyver88 Ah, sorry, I completely missed that.  I'll append it to my answer for completeness.  Thanks for the puzzle!

Comment: Ab jbeevrf. V jnfa'g guevyyrq jvgu ubj V yvaxrq rirelguvat va gur dhrfgvba. Vg jnf rnfl gb zvff. :)

Answer (score 2):

Partial guess for suffix:

> ER - emergency room, place to go with broken limbs, with brevity = use abbreviation