# Do I Get This Done Here?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

Another [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude). Enjoy.

> My Beginning has been truly proven. 
>   My Middle has plans, better check when. 
>   My End speaks, you should listen. 
>   Once together, my Green Check will be given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Beginning has been truly proven.

> valid - accepted as correct

My Middle has plans, better check when.

> date - don't be late

My End speaks, you should listen.

> TED - Technology, Entertainment, and Design - a conference which provides popular talks

Once together, my Green Check will be given.

> these fit together to be **validated**

Comment: That's the one. Nice work.