# My Parts Are The First Parts

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay, rhyme

Another riddle from ~ *Words That Get Stuck In MacGyver88's Head* ~(:P)

> My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.
>   For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.
>   My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation.
>   It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.
>   My ending is the first part of a very popular article.
>   To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.
>   So cleverly together, my pieces do raise.
>   Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.
>   What am I?

Hint 1

> [Riley riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) but no overlap

Hint 2

> length(beginning) = length(middle) = length(ending)

Hint 3

> length(type) = length(abbreviation) = length(article)

Comment: "Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise." - older siblings? (hehe)

Comment: So the other day, someone asked for more difficulty. This is my first attempt at more difficult. Still solvable, though. Don't worry. Somebody always figures these things out. No clues here; just an explanation to the puzzle's broadness.

Comment: I love it @MacGyver88

Comment: @anodyne, Thank you.  I personally like puzzles that aren't too rushed. I wanted to put this one out, but thought it was too simple. So I slept on it and figured it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> plinth?

My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.
For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.

> PLy, a way to categorize toilet paper/paper towels (typically 2 ply, can also be 1 or 3. I don't know that much about it, but generally the more plies used, the softer each ply can be while maintaining the same strength. Also relevant to plywood, which might be what the riddle is referring to with traction?), Ply is also a verb (action) with various [definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ply).

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation.
It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.

> INc, short for incorporated. Zamboni and Aviation (gin) are both companies

My ending is the first part of a very popular article.
To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.

> THe, the most common article in the English language. Not sure about the part about the particle though - perhaps simply because it's the longest particle, as noted by TCooper

So cleverly together, my pieces do raise.
Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.

> A plinth is a pedestal to hold up a statue. Presumably they are placed before the statue, but people don't typically notice the plinth as they are too busy looking at the statue.

Comment: Interested to see if this is right. Good answer regardless

Comment: This is it! You hit all the major points. I'll explain more on Monday when I'm not on mobile and can easily rot13. I left major clues in the puzzle. :)

Comment: rot13(V thrff gurer'f abguvat zber gb zragvba rkprcg, na bofpher pelcgvp pyhr jnf va gur ynfg fgnamn, "FBPYR" vf nabgure anzr sbe cyvagu. Nyfb, gur gjb yrggre tebhcf jrer va uvag gjb, naq gur guerr yrggre tebhcf jrer va uvag guerr.) Great job! Deciphering my thoughts is a difficult challenge for even me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> Cognitive

"My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.
For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction."

> For ' cog ' , which is the first part of cogwheel,which is a synonym for gear. In automobiles , usually we use the 2nd gear, however many use for different ' tractions' and road situations.

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation.
It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.

> For the middle part, ' nit '  , it's the first part of ' nitro ' , abbreviation of nitrous oxide engine which includes most of automobiles   from zamboni ice resurfacers to aeroplane engines.

My ending is the first part of a very popular article.
To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.

> For the ending, ' Ive ' it can be written as ' ' I've ' which is the short form of ' I have ' , the beginning of many articles. ( The first which comes to my mind is ' I've a dream ' by Martin Luther King)

So cleverly together, my pieces do raise.
Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.

> Lastly the role of cognition ( adjective is cognitive ) is largely underestimated and least praised in many circles of the society.

Comment: Not the intended answer. But good thinking.

Answer (score 2):

> **A Programming method**

*My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.*

> The function name

*For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.*

> parameters. You usually have a bunch of them to allow the method to get different results based on the input.

*It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.*

> Programs are used to get many things done, including aviation and zamboni.

*My ending is the first part of a very popular article.*

> A method ends in a bracket usually (depending on language), but I don't see how to connect that to an article.

*So cleverly together, my pieces do raise.
Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.*

> Without good functioning code, the machine will not work (properly). However, people don't notice that and usually don't praise a machine for how its internals are coded.

Comment: Clever guess. However, not the intended answer.

Comment: ...but *I like it!* (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Guess #2:**

Slightly refined to below, but still has major holes. Still thinking...

> DRIVERLESS;
>
>  "DRI-" same reason as below;
>  "-VER-" is the first part of "version"; i.e. of big machines like Zambonis/planes in production;
>  "-ESS" is the first part of "essay", which could be published as an "article" but I'm not sure why it would be "very popular";
>
>  Driverless drones can "raise" or fly but I don't think they're "last to get praised" so I guess it's back to the drawing board for me

**Guess #1:**

I've thought about this for the past day and this is the best I could come up with. Probably not right but I'll shoot my shot in the dark:

> **DRIVELINE**

*My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.

For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.*

> "DRI-" is the first part of "drive", which refers to FWD, RWD, 4WD or AWD, different types of powertrains that affect a car's traction and off-roadability. Drive is therefore both a type and an action. Most pedestrian cars have FWD or RWD ("two is normal")

*My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation.

It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.*

> "-vel-" is the first part and abbreviation of "velocity", which both a Zamboni and airplanes have.

*My ending is the first part of a very popular article.
To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.*

> "-ine"? This one could be anything. What is an article in this context?

*So cleverly together, my pieces do raise.

Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.*

> Though the driveline is the "first" to deliver power to the wheels, it's pretty much never praised by car critics, who instead prefer to appraise engine/power, aesthetics, or handling. Unsure about "pieces do raise".

As for the hints,

> The beginning/middle/end are each three letters long, and they don't overlap.

Comment: Good ideas. However, not the intended answer. I'll give another hint tomorrow if necessary. +1

Answer (score 2):

> **Stretcher**

My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.

> **STR** is the beggining of String which is a type of data in programation.

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation.

> **ETC** is the abbreviation of Etcetera

My ending is the first part of a very popular article.

> Here I'm not sure, but **HER** could be used as article despite is a pronoun

Comment: Not the intended answer. Good thinking, though. +1

Answer (score 2):

is it

> Elevation

My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.
For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.

> Ele -> elect / element

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation.
It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.

> Vat -> VAT stands for Velocity at Threshold (aviation) ,     VAT Value-Added Tax

My ending is the first part of a very popular article.
To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.

> Ion -> many words has -ion , though I'm not sure an ion is larger than a particle

So cleverly together, my pieces do raise.
Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.

> maybe I'm wrong but elevation raises, but I really have no clue if this has any connection with praising part or maybe even with the first part of the sentence

Comment: Not the intended answer. But good thinking.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be

> A domino

My beginning is the first part of a type or an action. For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.

> DO, the action of doing something

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation. It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.

> MI, abbreviation used for loads of stuff

My ending is the first part of a very popular article. To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.

> NO, as a grammar article

So cleverly together, my pieces do raise. Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.

> You raise domino pieces to form a line and the first to fall is the least impressive so the last to get praise

I am not completely sure and I couldn't find explanation for every clue but I have a feeling it could fit the description

Comment: Not the intended answer, but nice try.

Answer (score 1):

My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.
For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.

> Realised gender is also written as sex which fits better

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation.
It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.

> The words are listed in order Z - A so backwards
>  Both have "no" backwards in them
>  no is a common abbreviation for number

My ending is the first part of a very popular article.
To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.

> With SeNo i tried to fit this clue around Ra as it is the only word i could find that fits with the first two answers
>  Very popular article is very ambiguous. Let's go with Radio
>  It's beginnning "Ra" also stands for Radium. Larger than a particle = an atom

So cleverly together, my pieces do raise.
Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.

> Senora meaning lady in spanish fits to the saying "Ladies first"
>  Ladies getting praise last would be a hot topic that may or may not be true

Comment: Good thoughts. I'll plus one when you complete your answer.

Comment: I really liked my idea for the middle part and am trying so hard to fit the other clues around it. Gonna leave it as it stands, Will look forward to the answer

Answer (score 1):

**Guess #3**

You are a

> hearth

My beginning is the first part of a type or an action. For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.

> HEm - a type of stitch, as well as an action(you can "hem" a piece of clothing). A double hem is most common, but triple and other variations can provide different benefits or uses in some cases.

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation. It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.

> ARm - Advanced RISC Machine is a processor architecture based on a 32-bit reduced instruction set (RISC) computer. They're in.. most everything.

My ending is the first part of a very popular article. To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.

> THe - there are 3 articles in the (modern)English language; "a", "an", and "the". "The" is the largest and easiest to see.

So cleverly together, my pieces do raise. Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.

> A hearth in front of your fireplace is the first portion you come into contact with, but the praise is saved for the fireplace/fire/warmth itself. It's also a symbol for home, something many people put first, but as it's familiar, rarely praise

**Guess #2**

I think you are

> health

My beginning is the first part of a type or an action. For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.

> HEm - a type of stitch, as well as an action(you can "hem" a piece of clothing). A double hem is most common, but triple and other variations can provide different benefits or uses in some cases.

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation. It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.

> ALt - short for altimeter - Obvious in aviation - not sure if used by Zamboni's but assuming a variation of the one to determine the buffers altitude/height from the ice?

My ending is the first part of a very popular article. To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.

> THe - there are 3 articles in the (modern)English language; "a", "an", and "the". "The" is the largest and easiest to see.

So cleverly together, my pieces do raise. Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.

> health should always come first, for anyone, but we're slow to praise ourselves for maintaining good health as it is "expected"

**Guess #1**

I think it is

> breath

My beginning is the first part of a type or an action.
For type, two is normal, some use more for different traction.

> BR - Brake! More than two will offer different traction

My middle is the first part of a well-known abbreviation.
It's included in things from Zamboni to Aviation.

> ea, as in EA Sports, making NHL(Zamboni) to Flight Simulators (Aviation)

My ending is the first part of a very popular article.
To see it is simple, definitely larger than a particle.

> th - first part of 'the'

So cleverly together, my pieces do raise.
Though first, I'm usually the last to get praise.

> Arguably the first thing anyone does is breath, yet we rarely think about it or appreciate the fact we're breathing

Comment: This is a good attempt. I did add a third hint this morning that this doesn't quite satisfy. rot13(Gur guerr jbeqf gb gnxr yrggref sebz ner nyy gur fnzr yratgu.)

Comment: Ohhh - I was actually wondering about that. Read it as the exact same as the hint above - knew that had to be wrong. Maybe a sign it's time for more coffee.

Comment: Huh. Downvoted for consolidating *insert shrug emoji* weird

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I don't have any hints that only reveal little bits. However, with a 200 point bounty, I shouldn't say much.

Comment: I've been tempted to ask specific questions about some clues, but also, don't want to take the challenge out of the solve - I think you've done really well with clues/hints

Comment: I +1'd you on others to make up for the point loss for consolidating your answers. Sorry about that. I hope you enjoyed the puzzle. It was just a word in my head. Nothing special.