# I treat the wounded

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix heats
>   My infix greets
>   My suffix is elite
>   The wounded, I treat

Hint

> All my affixes are of the same length

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it:

> **solace**

*My prefix heats*

> **Sol** means Sun. **sol**ace.

*My infix greets*

> **ola** is hello in Portuguese. s**ola**ce

*My suffix is elite*

> **ace** is the best. sol**ace**

*The wounded, I treat*

> **solace** means comfort or consolation in a time of distress or sadness. Wounded are in distress.

The Hint:

> All my affixes are of the same length.
>  **sol** & **ace** are 3 letters. (so is **ola**, but that's not technically an affix)

Comment: Isn't the Spanish word written with a (silent) h, though?

Comment: Technically, the other parts aren't affixes either (the solution word doesn't actually consist of those parts added to one another, it's just a wordplayful coincidence), but we like to honour [the genre starter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62349/36023) by using those terms anyway.

Comment: @jafe my bad, 'Ola' is Portuguese, not Spanish (and your right, hola is Spanish). https://www.google.com/search?q=ola