# Triple Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, anagram, affix-riddle

Below we have three [Riley riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The trick here is that the three answers are anagrams of each other.
Can you find all three?

> **I**
>   In all, I am a soldier,
>   My prefix can be found on a plane,
>   My suffix is at the edge,
>   My infix is an island, in Spain.
>
> **II**
>   In all, I am a mockery,
>   My suffix comes with a charge,
>   My prefix was a Sumerian city,
>   My infix, a dwarf that is large.
>
> **III**
>   My prefix is what it's about,
>   My infix, an evil act,
>   My suffix tried to stop pizza,
>   In all, I am just an extract.

**Please explain each line in your answer.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the 3 anagrammatical solutions are:

> **IRONSIDE**, **DERISION** and **RESINOID**

*In all, I am a soldier,*
*My prefix can be found on a plane,*
*My suffix is at the edge,*
*My infix is an island, in Spain.*

> *In all:* An '[**IRONSIDE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironside_(cavalry))' was a nickname for a Puritan *soldier* fighting for Oliver Cromwell in the English Civil War.
>
>  *Prefix:* **IR** stands for ["Instrument rating"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_rating) - qualifications that must be held by a pilot before they are permitted to fly an *aeroplane*;
>  *Infix:* [**ONS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ons_Island) is an island in Galicia, Spain;
>  *Suffix:* The **SIDE** of an object is 'at the edge'. (Or even something that is **ONSIDE** might be 'at the edge'...)
>  <sub>*NB OP revealed in comments that their intended prefix here was actually **IRON**, being the name of the steel blade on a carpenter's [plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(tool)) tool...*</sub>

*In all, I am a mockery,*
*My suffix comes with a charge,*
*My prefix was a Sumerian city,*
*My infix, a dwarf that is large.*

> *In all:* **DERISION** is a synonym for 'mockery'.
>
>  *Prefix:* [**DER**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_(Sumer)) was a *Sumerian city*;
>  *Infix:*  [**ERIS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eris_(dwarf_planet)) is a *dwarf* planet, but one of the *largest* known to us;
>  *Suffix:* An **ION** is a *charged* particle.

*My prefix is what it's about,*
*My infix, an evil act,*
*My suffix tried to stop pizza,*
*In all, I am just an extract.*

> *In all:* A **RESINOID** can be a gum resin *extracted* from plants.
>
>  *Prefix:* '**RE**' in the subject line of an e-mail tells you *what it's about*;
>  *Infix:* A **SIN** is *an evil act*;
>  *Suffix:* [The **NOID**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Noid) was a character used in advertising for *Domino's Pizza* who would try and sabotage the pizza-making process ('stop pizza').

Comment: The infix of the second answer could also be [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eris_(dwarf_planet)).

Comment: @Ankoganit Ha! Was literally just changing that answer myself! (Great minds...)

Comment: Well done! Everything spot on with what I was looking for except the prefix of the first one. However, I am happy to accept what you've written.

Comment: Thanks @hexomino - would love to know what your intended first prefix was :) (And if you fancy a laugh, check the edit history to see what I initially thought the second infix was!)

Comment: @Stiv a little unusual but I was thinking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(tool)) use of plane and if you look down to the parts you can see what the blade is normally called.

Comment: @Stiv Ah, I had not heard of Paolo Risi, that is an unusual coincidence.

Comment: @hexomino Ah, I'll add a reference to that for completeness. And re Risi, neither had I - but Google had!