# Get up and Riley!

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay

My prefix is strangely vast
My infix is just you and me
My suffix's where this is asked
My whole makes you so grumpy

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might actually be

> Rouse

My prefix is strangely vast

> R.O.U.S. (Rodents of Unusual Size) from The Princess Bride  (thanks Avi for the hint)
>
>  **Originally:** Ro is a unit of volume (Egyptian)

My infix is just you and me

> Us

My suffix's where this is asked

> SE = Stack Exchange

My whole makes you so grumpy

> Rouse means to make angry or excited

Title

> Rouse also means 'cause to stop sleeping'

Comment: This is the correct answer, but the prefix is incorrect. Here's a hint: the [tag:knowledge] part is from rot13(Gur Cevaprff Oevqr)

Comment: @Avi thanks, I think I've found the right thing now.

Answer (score 6):

Could it be

> 'RUSE'?

---

My prefix is strangely vast

> 'RU' is a [song](https://genius.com/Even-vast-ru-lyrics) by Even **Vast** - making the RU 'strangely' Vast

My infix is just you and me

> 'US' - you and me, and no one else

My suffix's where this is asked

> 'SE' - for stack exchange where this is posted

My whole makes you so grumpy

> If you are on the wrong end of a ruse, which means 'trick', you are likely to be pretty grumpy about it!

Comment: *So* close, but unfortunately, that's not it.

Answer (score 1):

> souse

My prefix is strangely vast

> SO is the largest SE-related site. It's also strange to PSEers in that some of its norms are very different from SE sites'.

My infix is just you and me

> us

My suffix's where this is asked

> SE, not SO

My whole makes you so grumpy

> an alcoholic can definitely do that ([so does alcohol](https://www.addictioncenter.com/alcohol/is-alcohol-a-depressant/), but I don't think "souse" means alcohol)

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be

> fuse

My prefix is strangely vast

> fus -- Like fuss. When you start a fuss, the influence on those around you is "strangely" vast.

My infix is just you and me

> us

My suffix's where this is asked

> se -- Stack Exchange

My whole makes you so grumpy

> After having a short fuse, you may also feel grumpy.

Title: Get up and Riley!

> The wording suggests telling a kid (Riley) who's having a short fuse. *Riley! Get off the ground and behave!*

Comment: In fact, the "Riley" part of the title is in reference to [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude). It's a specific style of riddle.

Comment: @Avi Thanks, I'm aware *(I posted a few of those myself)*.