# My prefix is a moment, my infix comes before nouns

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

I just made this ['Riley riddle'](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude):

> My prefix is a moment,
> My infix comes before nouns,
> My suffix is an Indian currency,
> I keep you safe and sure.

**What am I?**

Hint 1:

> It is a 7-letter word.

Hint 2 (A very concise hint):

> It is almost a "job".

Comment: By Indian currency do you mean rupee or paise explicitly?? Or is it used in some hideous way??

Comment: @LakshaySura Revealing that would presumably spoil the puzzle.

Comment: Sure let the OP save that for themselves.

Comment: @Lakshay Just a hint; rupees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Kramii was very close, but the answer is probably:

> **MOTHERS**

*My prefix is a moment,*

> **MO** is short for 'moment' (as in, "I'll be with you in a mo...").

*My infix comes before nouns,*

> **THE** (definite article) precedes nouns grammatically when referring to them (as in, "The quick brown fox...").

*My suffix is an Indian currency,*

> The Indian currency (Rupees) can be shortened to "**Rs**".

*I keep you safe and sure*

> A mother nurtures her children through infancy, keeping them 'safe and sure' on the path to adulthood.

Re the hints:

> 1. 'MOTHERS' is indeed 7 letters long, and 2. The role of a mother is demanding and takes all your time and energy to do it right - hence it might be considered a full-time occupation, or 'job'...

Comment: You really got this. I thought nobody could solve this.

Comment: @math Sometimes these things just take time :) With riddles especially, it's not always clear at first what the right answer to each part is! One piece of advice (since you requested feedback): Use the title to help your solvers - hide an extra clue among its words somehow (e.g. calling this puzzle something like "We know best" might lead people to a certain song from Disney's *Rapunzel* which would aid the solve). Don't change this one now (or it'll change people's answers) but for any future riddles you do, try and come up with an extra clue in the title to round out the puzzle :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> Bithers

Prefix:

> Bit. As in "in a moment" = "in a bit"

Infix:

> "the" comes before nouns

Suffix:

> Rs is short for rupees

Safe and sure:

> Bithers are a wallet for bitcoin style currency

Also:

> Bithers has 7 letters

But:

> Im not sure how this is almost a job?

Comment: Nice answer, but there is still one more.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer was valid before, but the question have been [edited](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/100482/6) afterwards, so now this answer is a bit innacurate.

---

Are you a

> promise

My prefix is a moment,

> prom -- A big moment!

My suffix comes before nouns,

> se -- S.E. -- The written abbreviation for southeast, and is an adjective. Adjectives go before nouns.

My infix is an Indian currency,

> mi -- Slice the m to get "rni" -- invert the letters to get "inr" -- INR is the International Organization for Standardization currency code for the Indian rupee

I keep you safe and sure

> promise -- Like a promise does.

Hint 1:

> It is a 7 letter word -- promise is a 7 letter word.

Hint 2:

> It is almost a "job" -- If you make a promise, it is your job to keep it.

Comment: really great answer, but there is one more

Comment: You’ve got the infix and suffix switched.

Comment: @El-Guest Actually the question was edited by the OP once they realised they had the infix and suffix the wrong way round in the initial post - risky posted before the change, so their answer just looks invalid but *was* correct as per the wording of the question at the time :)

Comment: @Stiv Glad I wasn't not brain dead that time :-)