# A Hand-picked Piece

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, rhyme, poetry

Another riddle from ~ Words That Get Stuck In MacGyver88's Head ~(:P)

> The following is but a novice trial.
> No points expected nor a prize to win.
> For thoughts to paper helps to cease the rile.
> Another word was stuck. So, let's begin.
> Two pieces reach across a fractured style.
> To seal their fates, a hand-picked piece shall pin.
> The first included yet his deeds most vile.
> Those with authority dost name him thin.
> The other, once complete, is broken. While,
> Her essence still pertains to everythin'.
> Their link's sweet smell transformed with cryptic guile.
> For 'tis no longer theRe wolf name withIn.
> And thus completes my form with frown and smile.
> Another form I do exist here in.

Hint 1

> Here is a tip to curing all your woes.
>  Begin their bind by finding the Ten no's.

Hint 2

> Section 3 of 7 refers to this popular style of riddle. (yes, done with the theatrics)

Hint 3

> Section 1 and 2 are fluff and aren't too important. So, don't pay much attention to them for a solution. However, their existence makes hint 1 work.

Hint 4

> [Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) inflated into a sonnet 
>  Possible senses needed: Hearing, Smell, Sight

Hint 5

> Their link is aCi tpyrc style ofEulc (5)

Comment: Is `theRe` intentional?

Comment: It is intentional.

Comment: V unir n fgenatr srryvat gur svefg unys vf (Wbrl) ZREYVAB. Vg unf VA gb or erzbirq.

Comment: @msh210, rot13(Lbh'er qrsvavgryl ba gb fbzrguvat! Ohg gurer'f zber gb vg.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a reach, but:

> Perpetual

> Perpetrators of crimes do vile things, and that word thins to perp, which is what those in authority (cops) often call them

> Based on your hint 5, stanza 6 says the link is no longer the flower named with "ni". So I assumed you started with petunia and removed ni, getting petua for the link.

> The suffix is the hardest, but it was hinted that it could be "-al", 
>  as "-al" is the essence of "all" (Pertains to Everything). (OP edit)

Comment: Wow. rot13(Lbh fubhyq gel "-NY" sbe gur fhssvk. uggcf://jjj.qvpgvbanel.pbz/oebjfr/ny)

Comment: Congratulations. You got 2 out of three. The final piece is within your grasp.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! @MacGyver88. Can I edit this answer to reflect it? Not sure if that's the right protocol.

Comment: Definitely. Fix away.

Comment: I'm going to edit the last part to make it accurate to my intentions.

Comment: If you would like to add more, what do you think the frown and the smile represent?

Comment: rot13(Uzz, vg pbhyq ersre gb gur engure qenzngvp naq gurngevpny fglyr bs lbhe evqqyr?) @MacGyver88

Comment: Nope. rot13(Gung jnf gur erq ureevat gung cebonoyl fghzcrq znal n chmmyre. Gung naq gur arire raqvat angher bs gur cbrz vgfrys. "B" n pvepyr, n sebja nobir n fzvyr.)

Comment: rot13(Nu lrf, crecrghny, yvxr n pvepyr. Sbe n juvyr V gubhtug qenzn jnf vaibyirq nf n fhssvk, naq jvgu gur bgure nafjre fhttrfgvat Wbrl Zreyvab, V jnf guvaxvat gur jrveq pncvgnyvmngvba va fgnamn 6 jnf fhccbfrq gb fbzrubj trg gung gb zryb naq zrybqenzn! Ohg V pbhyqa'g trg nal snegure jvgu gung. Gunaxf sbe gur obhagl!) @MacGyver88

Comment: So what was up with the "10 no's"?

Comment: @AmosZoellner it's a demonstration of the hint form used in stanza six; you'll notice the T is capitalized. You're supposed to start at the end of the next word and reverse it: sonnet.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess:

> Manipulate
>  A piece which is hand picked has been manipulated

> Man can do vile things, and a very vile man is Saruman, which can be thinned to 'man'
>  Nipul is lupin backwards (or lupine shortened to lupin' like 'tis), a sweet smelling flower type named after a wolf, keyed by 'flower' (theRe wolf, smell, hand picked)
>  Ate refers to food that has been broken down and eaten, essence for man (taste)

But not sure how this keys to the 10 no's (other than being 10 letters) or to the cryptic "withIn"

Comment: First off, not the intended answer. Nice try. There are concepts in your answer that are the beginnings of the correct methods. Your clues: rot13(Ab gnfgr, Uvag 5 vf jbeqrq gung fcrpvsvp jnl sbe n ernfba.)

Comment: Let me correct myself. One method is a correct method. One method is the beginning a correct method. One method is not a correct method.