# Riley Riddles can be fruitful you know

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

My first [Riley riddle...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) Hope you enjoy!

> My prefix might mean I kicked you
> My suffix gives a value.
> My infix might be a mother
> Altogether it has a bright colour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a

> Banana?

My prefix might mean I kicked you

> Ban

My suffix gives a value

> A? As in A-values [A-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_value#:%7E:text=A%2DValues%20are%20numerical%20values,of%20a%20monosubstituted%20cyclohexane%20chemical.) or NA as in the error value? (Previous answer)

> **New answer:** A. As in "one". *A* gives a value of 1.

My infix might be a mother

> Ana? (previous answer)

> **New answer:** Nan. An abbreviation of nanny. [Nan](https://www.etymonline.com/word/nan)

Altogether it has a bright colour

> Banana

Comment: The answer is correct, but the suffix and infix are wrong. +1!

Comment: @Bass im not sure what you mean. The suffix is the correct word as in A but not the right reasoning, the infix is wrong.

Comment: @Stevo V frr. Vf vg N nf va "Bar" juvpu unf in
yhr 1?

Comment: @Prim3numbah Yes! But the infix is still wrong...

Comment: @Stevo Updated now.

Comment: Congratulations!