# Some say I'm part of the solution

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

My prefix has won the fights
My infix marks the start of flights
My suffix you can almost solve
My whole makes friendly rubber revolve

What am I?

**Hint 1:**

> You could say my prefix was chosen

**Hint 2:**

> The opposite of my prefix once continued fighting for too long

**Hint 3:**

> My suffix is almost beyond understanding

**Hint 4:**

> My wikipedia-article says: "[The solution] is the ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ concerned with the relationship between ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ difference"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to this should be:

> **[ELECTROCHEMISTRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemistry)**

*My prefix has won the fights*

> The **ELECT** is the person/group that has won an election or vote. Re Hint 1, it literally means 'chosen'.
>
>  (Alternatively, the intent here may be a clue for *ELECTRO*, the name of a Puerto Rican [wrestler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro_(wrestler)) and a *Spider-Man* [supervillain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro_(Marvel_Comics)), both of whom have 'won the fights' on several occasions...)

*My infix marks the start of flights*

> In darts, the **OCHE** is a line on the floor behind which the darts must be thrown at the board. The darts 'start their flights' from here.

*My suffix you can almost solve*

> The suffix is **MISTRY**, a soundalike of sorts for 'MYSTERY' - something tricky to solve (or 'almost beyond understanding', as per Hint 3).

*My whole makes friendly rubber revolve*

> **ELECTROCHEMISTRY** underpins the electric power found in an [electric battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery). Such a battery might be found in an electric car - an environmentally-*friendly* way to make *rubber* tyres *revolve*...

As for the title...

> Electric cars might be 'part of the solution' for tackling global warming, hence electrochemistry itself might have a substantial role to play here.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Note: *This solution was submitted before user realized this was an affix riddle*</sub>

---

Is the answer:

> thrust?

*My prefix has won the fights*

> You use the thrust of your arm to win a fight

*My infix marks the start of flights*

> The thrust of a jet engine starts flights

*My suffix you can almost solve*

> The first 2 lines last 3 letters are ***h, t, and s***, all of which are in thrust

*My whole makes friendly rubber revolve*

> Thrust also makes rubber revolve, as the rubber is a car tire.

Comment: This would be a good answer for a normal riddle, but unfortunately this is an [tag:affix-riddle], [see this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) for how they work - the final answer gets split up into different parts

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.